Are there any everyday effects of the details of QCD physics?
This is perhaps a bit of an odd question, but here goes. When physicists stared investigating atomic nuclei, it turned out that protons and neutrons were composite, and the force binding them into nuclei was a complicated result of the strong interactions among their component quarks and gluons. Could it have turned out differently, without affecting the phenomena of everyday life? Could a universe very much like ours (at least to casual observation!) exist where instead protons and neutrons were elementary particles, and an elementary scalar field bound them in nuclei with a Yukawa force?
(Edit: for clarification, I'm imagining that protons and neutrons in this scenario would be related in the same way as electrons and neutrinos, and the details of the electroweak interaction are the same as in our universe.)

The isospin symmetry indicates that neutrons & protons aren't independent. And independence would make it tricky to explain beta decay, although that's governed by the weak interaction.

For what it's worth, in the low energy effective theory describing "ordinary" nuclear physics (sometimes known as Chiral perturbation theory), the forces between nucleons are mediated by a set of massive scalar fields called pions. In principle, based on how effective field theories work to work, I would expect any UV theory that generated chiral perturbation theory as a low energy effective theory would have basically the same nuclear phenomena that we observe.

@Andrew I find the neutron decay/recombination reaction ($p \rightarrow n+e$
and $p+e \rightarrow n$) really bizarre, as the $u$ and $d$ quarks reside inside the nucleon while $e$ resides outside, e.g. the LHS lives in Canada while the RHS lives in the US... how/where do you think these {u, d, e} are reacting, exactly on the boundary of the nucleon?

The decay is mediated by W and Z bosons (and involves an anti-neutrino to conserve lepton number.) In a low energy effective theory, the nucleons can be treated as point particles and the weak-force bosons replaced by a contact interaction between electrons and nucleons.

@TLDR As the quarks are exclusively inside the nucleon while the electron being exclusively outside, how/where would they perform a "transaction" with one another since they can't occupy the same space? If Alice and Bob is in Canada and Charlie is in the US, it seems that they need to meet locally either in Canada or US for an instant to transact, right?

@James electrons are not exclusively outside the nucleon. The whole point of deep inelastic scattering is that they can be inside; moreover, when you talking about scattering, inside/outside isn't a thing. See, e.g. (search, that is) 'Stanley brodsky constituent counting rules'

@JEB thank you, I forgot about deep inelastic scattering. Supposing for a second that the electron does not enter the proton, could the internal structure patterns found in deep inelastic scattering have been generated due to the electron grazing close to the u-d-u structure from different directions, or does deep inelastic scattering conclusively prove that the electrons must have shot through inside the proton?

@James In relativistic field theory, locality and causality essentially require interactions to be point-like. In Weinberg QFT I, this is presented as why quantum fields are introduced in the first place (rather than positing interactions directly in terms of particle states.) "Low energy" EFTs approximate nucleons as point particles: the complexities of the "transaction" are integrated into "spin" degrees of freedom (which are somewhat more complex in EFTs.)

@James In the standard model, the $n$ and $p$ bound states are described by an ensemble of quarks and gluons. Electrons interact with quarks through the electroweak force, via local couplings to W and Z bosons that gluons are not immediately coupled to. There is no exclusion principle preventing quarks and bosons from inhabiting the same point, and the roughness of "typical" paths in the path integral essentially guarantees that they will meet.

@TLDR thank you. For some reason, I am hung up about the electron not being able to enter the proton... Is the QCD vacuum mathematically the same vacuum as the QED vacuum? Since they are two separate QFT theories after all, and QCD objects (quarks, gluons) are constrained to be within its nucleon domain, what makes QED objects (electrons, photons) free to wander into the nucleon domain where QCD reigns?

@TLDR it seems that ordinary QED photons also have difficulty interacting with the nucleus: "In order for a photon to interact with the nucleus, the photon must have an energy of millions of eVs. So it is difficult to create or find sources of the high energy gamma rays needed to interact with the protons in a nucleus." ( https://www.quora.com/Do-photons-interact-with-the-nucleus ) If only specially prepared very high energy photons can interact with the nucleus, can normal energy electrons enter the nucleus?

To my knowledge, direct proton decay has yet to be observed. Inverse beta decay and electron capture on the other hand are fairly common.  In a low energy effective theory (e.g. QED), these processes might be added directly to the Lagrangian as interaction terms. The resulting theory might then be non-unitary (i.e. stochastic), or incorporate additional variables accounting for internal structure.

QCD gives us nuclei, and therefore atoms when QED is included. No QCD means no atoms and no universe as we know it.

In our universe, obviously. I'm asking whether there's a possible hypothetical universe where something other than QCD gives us nuclei which still behaves similarly at low energies. Why bother posting an answer if you haven't read the question?

I read the question. I obviously didn't get what you were after. Let's see if anyone else bothers to answer it.
